# How to locate or hide the slide in multi-channel

Tags: devextreme

All my pages are listed in the mobile , i want to be able to first hide  them and display them when necessary

I want to display only the login page and hide all other page

I want to edit the name of those  page[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question above is on devextreme(a tool for mobile) not many  developers are not using this tool.

All you need to do is to locate the a particular file. eg applicationname.config.js

The applicationname is the name of your project followed by .congig.js

In the file , object must be a valid JSON see below example

```
 "config": {
    "layoutSet": "navbar",
    "navigation": [
        {
            title: "Home",
            onExecute: "#home",
            icon: "home"
        },
        {
            title: "About",
            onExecute: "#about",
            icon: "info"
        }
    ]
   }
```

That is how the file looks like

So, you can add a view or remove a view